# why printf() is printing double variable as f char?

Tags: c, printf

i am trying to print double variable using printf function.
using this function

```
 int x_angle,y_angle;
 double xc, ret, val;

 x_angle=mouse_shoot.x-10; 
 y_angle=19-mouse_shoot.y;
 xc=y_angle/x_angle;
 val = 180.0 / PI;
 ret = atan (xc) * val;
 printf("The arc tangent of %f is %f degrees", xc, ret);
```

x_angle and y_angle printed just fine , but when i am trying to print xc and ret i am getting this print

"The arc tangent of f is f degrees"
any idea why?

----*UPDATE*-----

seems like Dos is not printing double to screen so i casted the result to int
and it printed fine!

Comment: Please post a code that we can compile . Where is the `main` ?

Comment: main is not relavent because i am doing a real time game in dos , i run this function from somewhere in the code and i am getting this output

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget the `%` before the `f`? And make sure that `x_angle` here `xc=y_angle/x_angle` isn't zero. If you stil get the same output, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnColeman It is just for `scanf` not necessary in `printf` .

Comment: yes i tried with %lf aswell same results , i printed x_angle and y_angle both not zeros

Comment: guys do you think that printing to dos what causing the problem ,because i tried printing double variable somewhere else same thing f char!!

Comment: You should specify your system and compiler

Comment: My guess - some #define is switching out printf floating-point support.

Comment: when asking a run time question,  the posted code needs to minimal, complete, compiles cleanly, and running it still shows the problem.   I.E post a main() function that drives the posted function,  be sure to post the #include statements you are using.

Comment: you want to me post 1k+ code so you can the run the main ,like i said main is ireleavent

Comment: what is `mouse_shoot`?   what are the values in the fields when this code malfunctions?

Comment: regarding this line: `xc=y_angle/x_angle;`   this is performing integer math.  if `y_angle < x_angle` then xc will contain 0.0

Comment: after changing: `xc=y_angle/x_angle;` to this: `xc  = (1.0*y_angle)/x_angle;` then using 0 for both x_angle and y_angle results in the output showing -nan and -nan, which indicates an overall logic problem.  using 10 for x_angle and 19 for y_angle results in -1.900000 and -62.215569. such drastic differences, depending on the x_angle and y_angle values indicates (to me) that the logic is flawed.   In either case, a valid output was produced.   Suggest when compiling to enable all the warnings then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: just solved by casting the double to int , i tried printing a double value like 0.5 save result gives me f char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `xc = y_angle / x_angle` gives problems since both angles are integers?

Try casting them to `double` maybe:

```
((double)y_angle) / ((double)x_angle)
```

Comment: This wouldn't cause `printf` to print what OP is getting. This should be a comment IMO.